# dealing with foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-design

i am creating a doctor appointment system, and i did include prescriptions too

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

i was thinking what if the doctor delete his account for some reasons, can the doctor or the clinic set to null if this happen?

Comment: It's your choice.

Comment: thank you for answering, but is it acceptable for a prescription to have doctor or clinic set to null?

Comment: I think so. If I were you, I would create a new field called display name and put the name of the doctor so that when the doctor deletes his or her account, the prescription still has the name of him or her.

Comment: that would create some redunduncy, but i think that's the only option, thank you for answering me

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yeah i was going to do that, i mean adding the name to the model, but i thought it's not good practice since it will add redundancy, so i wanted to ask first before i do it if there's a better method

Comment: Okay, that's cool

Comment: do you think it will be better, if i create another table to be like an archive for information about doctors like the name to avoid redundancy? @bichanna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `doctor_name` and `clinic_name` fields in your models.py:

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    doctor_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

And add the doctor's name and the name of the clinic each time. However, this is very redundant....

Actually, here iss stackoverflow's database schema -> [url](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381168/stack-overflow-database-model).
As you can see, there's `OwnerDisplayName` so that posts still have author's name.